# Render HTML string in Node?

Tags: html, node.js, rendering

Alright, so I have downloaded Express, set the port with `process.env.PORT || 8080`, and set the app variable `var app = express()`. Now, what I'm trying to accomplish is instead of rendering HTML through a file, could I do it through a string?

```
var html = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n    <head>\n    </head>\n <body>\n      <h1>Hello World!</h1>\n   </body>\n</html>";
app.get('/',function(req,res){
   res.render(html);
});
```

Is there a possible way to do this?

Comment: Use `res.send(html);`

Comment: You shouldn't put HTML code in your controller.  Instead use a template engine like [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/)

Comment: @aaronbartell I can send HTML like this: `res.send("<h1>Hello World!</h1>")` but not in a variable. Why can't I send it in a variable?

Comment: @baranskistad, I found that doing `res.end(htmlVar);` works while `res.send(htmlVar);` does not

Answer (score 32, accepted):

the `res.render` method as specified in the doc : **Renders a view and sends the rendered HTML string to the client.** So you need to use a template engine eg : jade,ejs, handlebars.. but if your purpose is to only output some html you can do it with `res.send` instead.

Comment: Could help me on this.I want to combine two html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57234830/how-to-generate-dynamic-html-based-on-json?noredirect=1#comment100972687_57234830

Answer (score 8):

Use `res.setHeader` set `HTTP Response Header`

```js
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html")
  res.send(`
  <h1>Mock API</h1>
  `)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a string but then you should convert the call to a Javascript call so only the part that needs to be replaced is displayed on the web page. The Ajax call gets from the Controller a : `res.send("This is a String)` back to its client. At the client you could put this `result` in a elements `innerHtml` and then you will have some kind of SPA :-)