# Running an html response without opening the browser

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, request

I'm trying, using node.js (request package), to get a server response of html file, adding a script to it and run this file with the script.

The `node.js`:

```
const request= require ('request')
const fs = require  ('fs')
request.get ('www.google.com', (err, data, body) => {
if (err) throw err
body+='<script src="script.js"></script>'
fs.writeFile ('h.html', body)
})
```

The `script.js`:

```
window.onLoad = () =>alert ('something')
```

How can I do it without saving the response in html file and open it in the browser?

Comment: What issue are you having getting and serving the file? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are getting, where you are loading it and how you are changing it? For example, Are you loading the HTML file in Node.js and then appending the JS file to it?

Comment: I added an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can do the following:**

```
var templateHtml = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body>Your HTML</body></html>";
app.get('/your_resource',function(req,res){
    res.send(templateHtml);
});
```

Of course, you need to replace in `templateHtml` the script.

**Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38310388/1715121) to get more info about how to use HTML templates.**

For example, imagine you have the package `express-es6-template-engine` in your project.

**NodeJs**

```
var express = require('express'),
    es6Renderer = require('express-es6-template-engine'),
    app = express();

app.engine('html', es6Renderer);
app.set('views', 'views');
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', {locals: {title: 'Welcome!', script: '<script>//script.js</script>'}});
});

app.listen(3000);
```

**Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ${script}
</head>
<body>
<h1>${title}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**Hope it helps!**