# How to generate dynamic html based on JSON?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js

I am implementing server side rendering pages, For server side rendering I am using  HTML, Node.js HandleBars. So From client side I am sending static HTML, JSON DATA. Handlebar will bind data with static page(In Node side). And in response I am getting HTML page with data.

**Structure Of Code Below:**

```
module.exports.renderTemplate = function (templateData, htmlSource) {
  // I am getting dynamicElement JSON
  // generate HTML dynamic element?
  // How to add with final HTML.
  template = Handlebars.compile(htmlSource);      
  html     = template(templateData);     
  return(html)
}
```

Above code giving me final HTML, Below I am attaching console.log code.

**htmlSource**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>{{staticElement.title}}</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../_global/xlib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div>
      <a href="javascript:;" class="hamburger-icon"></a>
      <h2 class="page-title">{{staticElement.title}}</h2>
    </div>  
  </header>
  <main>
    <section class="card-container container-component">
      <div class="card">      
        <h2>{{staticElement.text1}}</h2>       
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <i class="icons import-enrollment-icon"></i>
        <h2>{{staticElement.text2}}</h2>

      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <script src="../../_global/xlib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  <script src="../../../scripts/utils.js"></script>
  <script src="../../_global/scripts/utils.js"></script>
  <script src="home.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**templateData**

```
   { staticElement:
       { title: 'JHON',
         text1: 'Ameo',            
         text2: 'Start'        
    },
    {dynamicElement:
                 {"myBooks": [{
                               "Book ID": "1",
                               "Book Name": "Computer Architecture",
                               "Category": "Computers"                
                               },
                               {
                               "Book ID": "2",
                               "Book Name": "Asp.Net 4 Blue Book",
                               "Category": "Programming"             
                                }        
                              ] 
                    }
      }
```

**Final HTML:**

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>{{staticElement.title}}</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../_global/xlib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <header>
        <div>
          <a href="javascript:;" class="hamburger-icon"></a>
          <h2 class="page-title">JHON</h2>
        </div>  
      </header>
      <main>
        <section class="card-container container-component">
          <div class="card">      
            <h2>Ameo</h2>       
          </div>
          <div class="card">           
            <h2>Start</h2>

          </div>
        </section>
      </main>
      <script src="../../_global/xlib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>  
      <script src="../../../scripts/utils.js"></script>
      <script src="../../_global/scripts/utils.js"></script>
      <script src="home.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

When I want to create document.write. Then it is not working. because document.write will work with browser.
I want to add **dynamicElement** JSON Data into the final HTML Without hard coding html tags, Means in future 5 or 10 json value will come in dynamicElement then no need to write html tag.

I am new in the handleBar and node side rendering. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would need to store or return the rendered HTML back to the browser, what are you using to server your SSR HTML? Express? Koa? other? basically your server/middleware/router would handle serving the rendered HTML back to the browser, no need for document.write

Comment: @exside Thanks for the comment, I am using SSR HTML(example data-ssr-include). If you have still little bit idea please share you thought and answer. Your effort will be appreciated.

Comment: I can't understand why you're using the server just to combine some HTML and JSON.  Handlebars can be used on the client.  So, if you already have the handlebars template and the JSON on the client, you can just use the a client-side version of handlebars and render it to HTML which you can then dynamically insert into the DOM (not with `document.write()`, but with `.appendChild()` or `.insertBefore()` or some DOM insertion method like that).

Comment: @jfriend00 This is my project structure, I have to follow the same. All these thing should be done by in server side because of some security aspects.